# Prevent a computer from entering Sleep/Standby/Hibernate while program is running

Tags: vb.net

I tried these code but doesn't work.

I'm using Windows 10 and VS 2019 (VB.NET).

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    <FlagsAttribute()> _
    Public Enum EXECUTION_STATE As UInteger
        ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &H1
        ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &H2
        ES_CONTINUOUS = &H80000000UI
    End Enum

    <DllImport("Kernel32.DLL", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function SetThreadExecutionState(ByVal state As EXECUTION_STATE) As EXECUTION_STATE
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It shows nothing, my computer stil sleep.

Comment: ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED only resets the system's idle timer.  Which then keeps on ticking to trigger a sleep if you don't also include ES_CONTINUOUS.

Comment: You missed [ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetThreadExecutionState.html) somehow, it requires including ES_CONTINUOUS.  When used it even prevents the user from putting the machine to sleep.

Comment: How to convert 0x00000040 into VB.NET for ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED value?

Comment: @frozenade : A bit late to the party, but to convert the number to VB.NET (it's represented in hexadecimal, by the way) you just need to replace `0x` with `&H`. Like this: `&H00000040` (or just `&H40` for brevity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `ES_CONTINUOUS` as well, otherwise you only reset the idle timer once.

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate):

> Calling **SetThreadExecutionState** without **ES_CONTINUOUS** simply resets the idle timer; to keep the display or system in the working state, the thread must call **SetThreadExecutionState** periodically.

```
SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED Or EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS)
```

If you at a later point wish to undo this and make the system able to put itself to sleep again, call the function and specify only `ES_CONTINUOUS`.

Comment: Thank you. My system is now completely wake up all the time. I'm using SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED Or EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS or EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED)